# Conditional expectation in Beta-Binomial Model

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution, bayesian

I have a beta-binomial model given as

\begin{align}
Y|\theta &\sim Bin(n, \theta) \\
\theta &\sim Beta(\alpha, \beta).
\end{align}

If I am observing $Y=y$, then my posterior is
\begin{align}
\theta|Y=y \sim Beta(\alpha + y,\beta +n -y).
\end{align}

Now, what I like to find is an expression for the conditional expectation of $\theta$ given that I observe *at least* $Y=y$, i.e., how can I find

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\theta |Y \ge \underline{y})
\end{align}
? Any hint or help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.